# LazyList 's listview can not refresh with new arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview, lazylist

I m trying to use searchView with LazyList. In my lazyAdapter I m updating my arraylist , this works smoothly but my listview doesn't update with arrayList. This is my filer method. I suppose notifyDataSetChanged does not work.Please help how can I refresh my listview?

```
public void filter(String charText) {

    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    //list.clear();
    list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        list.addAll(arraylist);
    } 
    else 
    {
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : arraylist) 
        {
            if (map.get("radio").toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
            {
                list.add(map);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: re-set the adapter for listview such this lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `list` holds a different object after the third line. You are changing this new `ArrayList` but the adapter still remembers the old one. Instead of

```
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

write

```
list.clear();
```

You then work with the same object as before.

Answer (score 1):

> LazyList 's listview can not refresh with new arraylist

Because you are not adding new list in current Adapter of Listview before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` :

Add `list` to adapter using `addAll` method:

```
listviewAdapter.addAll(list);
//notify data-source change to adapter
 notifyDataSetChanged();
```

if `addAll` method not available then create a method in Adapter class and pass list as parameter then call add method:

```
public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
     for(String item: data) {
         add(item);
       }
       notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class MovieListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> movielist;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listAdapter;

        public MovieListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> movielist) {
            this.context = context;
            this.movielist = movielist;
            this.listAdapter = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            this.listAdapter.addAll(movielist);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return movielist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return movielist.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View griView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_listitem, null);
            TextView textview = (TextView) griView.findViewById(R.id.catname);

            textview.setText(movielist.get(position).get("name"));
            textview.setSelected(true);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) griView.findViewById(R.id.catimage);

            DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int width = metrics.widthPixels / 3;
            int height = metrics.widthPixels / 3;

            // System.out.println(movielist.get(position).getMoviepicture());

            if (movielist.get(position).get("image").equals("")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blankart);
            } else {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(movielist.get(position).get("image"))
                        .resize(width, height).placeholder(R.drawable.blankart)
                        .noFade().into(imageView);
            }
            return griView;
        }

        public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            movielist.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                movielist.addAll(listAdapter);
            } else {
                for (HashMap<String, String> si : listAdapter) {
                    if (si.get("name").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(charText)) {
                        movielist.add(si);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    make you adapter like this
```